# Not Serializable: com/salesforce/api/fast/List$$lcom/salesforce/api/Database/Error$$r

Tags: apex, visualforce

I am getting the foll error while displaying a wrapper class in VF page

> Not Serializable:
>   com/salesforce/api/fast/List$$lcom/salesforce/api/Database/Error$$r

Here cr is a list of a wrapper class.

```
<apex:pageBlock rendered="{!if(showConverted==true, true,false)}">  
<apex:pageBlockSection columns="1" > 

            <apex:outputText value="{!errMsg}"   />

</apex:pageBlockSection>
<apex:pageBlockSection columns="1" title="Following Leads were successfully converted">
    <apex:pageBlockTable id="conversionResults" value="{!cr}" var="s">

        <apex:column headerValue="Lead" >
            <apex:outputText value="{!s.leadname}"   />
        </apex:column> 
        <apex:column headerValue="Opportunity" >
            <apex:outputLink value="/{!s.oppId}" rendered="{!if(s.oppId == null || s.oppId =='', false,true)}"> {!s.oppName} </apex:outputLink>
        </apex:column>
        <apex:column headerValue="Account" >
            <apex:outputLink value="/{!s.accId}" rendered="{!if(s.accId == null || s.accId =='', false,true)}"> {!s.AccountName} </apex:outputLink>
        </apex:column>
        <apex:column headerValue="Contact" >
            <apex:outputLink value="/{!s.contactId}" rendered="{!if(s.contactId == null || s.contactId =='', false,true)}"> {!s.Contactname} </apex:outputLink>
        </apex:column>
    </apex:pageBlockTable>
</apex:pageBlockSection>
```

Here is the wrapper class

```
public class conversionResult
     {
        public Id leadId {get; set;}
        public Id contactId {get; set;}
        public Id oppId {get; set;}
        public Id accId {get; set;}
        public String Leadname {get; set;}
        public String AccountName {get; set;}
        public String Contactname {get; set;}
        public String oppName {get; set;}

        public conversionResult(Id Lead_v,Id Account_v,Id Contact_v,Id opportunity_v)
        {

            this.leadId = Lead_v;
            this.accId = Account_v;
            this.contactId = Contact_v;
            this.oppId = opportunity_v;
            this.Leadname ='';
            this.AccountName ='';
            this.Contactname ='';
            this.oppName ='';

        }
     }
```

I can see in the debug logs that cr is populated correctly. I couldnt find anything on this error on documentation or on google.Any pointers would be helpful

Comment: I'm also facing the same problem in one of my batch class where I try to delete the content from "Salesforce CRM Content" object. Which store the content in libraries. Error: System.SerializationException: Not Serializable: com/salesforce/api/fast/List$$lcom/salesforce/api/Database/DeleteResult$$r

Comment: Just a note, you can always replace `IF(condition, true, false)` with simply `condition`, and `IF(condition, false, true)` with `NOT(condition)`.

Comment: Is that the whole wrapper class or a snippet?